# Why do I get this error on my Mac using Texmaker: "File not found"?

Tags: texmaker

I keep getting this error: `file not found`. I am using a Mac Pro 2019.

[image]

```
 %  %  \documentclass[12pt]{article} \usepackage{graphicx} 
 \usepackage{amsmath}  \usepackage{amssymb}  \usepackage{amsfonts} 
 \usepackage{amsthm}  \usepackage{longtable}  \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{color} \usepackage{relsize} \input{epsf} % \input xy
 \xyoption{all} % %\usepackage{showkeys} \usepackage{latexsym} % %
 \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section] 
 \newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem} 
 \newtheorem{proposition}[lemma]{Proposition} 
 \newtheorem{corollary}[lemma]{Corollary} 
 \newtheorem{conjecture}[lemma]{Conjecture} 
 \newtheorem{construction}[lemma]{Construction} 
 \newtheorem{example}[lemma]{Example} 
 \newtheorem{definition}[lemma]{Definition} 


 % Tweak the margins to match requirements. Seems to work OK. 
 \topmargin-0.5cm  \footskip1cm  \oddsidemargin0.5cm 
 \evensidemargin0cm  \textwidth16cm  \textheight21cm  \vfuzz1pc 
 \hfuzz1pc 


 % Tweak chapter headings  %\titleformat{\chapter}[display] 
 %{\sc\Huge\center}{\chaptername\,\,\thechapter}{0pt}{}{} 

 \newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{\underline{id}}}  %\newcommand{\id}{\} 

 \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}} 

 % A 'Proof' environment.  % This is done with the extra commands made
 available from theorem  %\theoremstyle{nonumberplain} 
 %\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\itshape} 
 %\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}  %\theoremseparator{.} 
 %\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}  %\newtheorem{pf}{Proof} 


 \renewcommand{\Gamma}{\varGamma}  \renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}
 \renewcommand{\bar}{\overline}  \renewcommand{\hat}{\widehat} 

 \renewcommand{\leq}{\leqslant}  \renewcommand{\geq}{\geqslant} 


 %Extra things that are included for simplicity. 

 \newcommand{\Po}{\mathcal{P}} \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
 \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}  \newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}  % % 
 \newcommand{\Sym}{\mathrm{Sym}} 

 \newcommand{\vt}{\mathrm{vert}} \newcommand{\conv}{\mathrm{conv}}
 \newcommand{\Fix}{\mathrm{Fix}} \newcommand{\Span}{\mathrm{Span}}

 \newcommand{\rank}{\mathrm{rank}} 

 \begin{document}    BODY
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably show some code and exactly what the error is. Did you remember to install latex. (e.g. Mactex)

Comment: yes I did, how to show my code?

Comment: Update your question, the site have nice features to show code

Comment: @daleif I did it

Comment: And what exactly is the error, preferably cited directly from the log, not the ones filtered in texmaker.

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

Comment: Btw: the definitions for Sym, vert, conv, Fix, Span, rank are all wrong. Look up DeclareMathOperator

Comment: they worked in my previous laptop,

Comment: That error does not make sense with this mwe. There is also problems from the first lines from this mwe. Are you sure this is exactly what you are compiling

Comment: It is not that they did not work, the definitions does not give the correct spacings. `$2\rank B$` should have a small space after the 2 and before the B, your definition does not.

Comment: yes, this is also another :! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ‎ (U+200E)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...arger{\mathlarger{‎‎\sum}}_{m \in M}

Comment: No offense, but please don't waste our time with minimal examples citing errors that are not related to the code presented. Take your time and present a proper question with proper code related to the problem you present. We are not a live crystal ball debugging feature